# how to change the font size of label in <v-checkbox> Vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to change the font size of "attendance",which is the content of label.

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="course.evaluation"
  label="attendance"
></v-checkbox>
```

Here is what I've tried. Inside the same vue file, I added

```
<style>
.v-checkbox.v-label {
  font-size: 10px;
} 
</style>
```

But it didn't work. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 5):

Try increasing priority by adding chaining selectors

Add a `class` to the checkbox

```
<v-checkbox
  class="my-checkbox"
  v-model="course.evaluation"
  label="attendance"
></v-checkbox>
```

Then

```
<style>
.my-checkbox .v-label {
  font-size: 10px;
} 

or In case it still doesn't reflect the override then use deep selector

::v-deep .my-checkbox .v-label {
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using wrong css selectors. You may solve your problem this way:

```
<style>
  .v-input--checkbox .v-label {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

But keep in mind that if your component contain more than one v-checkboxes, **all of them** will have their font changed.

Another solution is to override **label** slot this way:

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="course.evaluation">
  <template v-slot:label>
    <span style="font-size: 10px">attendance</span>
  </template>
</v-checkbox>
```